# How to rename a Google chrome extension or completely hide it in ‘Manage extensions’?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons

I want to rename or hide an extension on the family computer on Google Chrome. I am on Windows 10. How do I do that ?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

To modify an extension is only possible if it is not yet installed,
so uninstall it first.

Now do:

- Install the extension
  [Chrome Extension Source Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin?hl=en)
- Click the "Extensions" icon and set the check-mark next to the extension
- Position to your extension in the
  [chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions)
- Click the icon of the Chrome Extension Source Viewer extension
  (CRX) and select "Download as ZIP"
- Unpack the Zip file into a separate folder
- Delete the `_metadata` folder
- Modify the file `manifest.json` with your data
- Go to `chrome://extensions` in Chrome
- Select "developer mode"
- Click "load unpacked extension" and select the entire folder containing
  the extension source
- Done.

For more information with screenshots see the article
[How to Edit Chrome Extensions](https://www.superside.com/blog/how-to-edit-and-customize-chrome-extensions).

Comment: Thank you I will try